# Can the property search function in a browser's console be replicated programatically?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, console

In the browser dev tools console you can search for things.
In this instance it is some information held in a script variable and is in JSON format.

So I have some questions:
1 - Is there a way to replicate this console search in javascript?
2 - Where is this information actually held, is it in memory? Some of the details in that JSON have been updated by javascripts after page load, it is no longer the same version that you can get from the page source HTML.

[image]

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Seems odd you would be testing a site via the console.

Comment: I'm just referencing the console to show that the value has been updated and asking how that manages to do it as I need a similar solution. Personally don't think it's an xy question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using the appropriate browser document window;

```js
function GetDocWindow()
{  
  var document, window;
  document = Sys.Browser().Page("*").contentDocument
  // Check if the document.parentWindow property is available
  if (aqObject.IsSupported(document, "parentWindow")){
    window = document.parentWindow //ie browser
    Log.Message("Document type in use is 'parentWindow'")
    }

  // Check if the document.defaultView property is available
  else if (aqObject.IsSupported(document, "defaultView")){
    window = document.defaultView //chrome browser
    Log.Message("Document type in use is 'defaultView'")  
    }
  else
    Log.Error("Unknown browser that doesn't support document.parentWindow or document.defaultView.");
  
  return window
}
```

the "aqObject" is native to smartbear's testComplete software but hopefully this will help along anyone that is looking for something similar as I had trouble getting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to monitor (and intercept) changes made to the object.

```js
digitalData = new Proxy(digitalData, {  
  set: function (target, key, value) {
    target[key] = value;
    // updated object
    console.log({ target });
    return true;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will give that a whirl.

Comment: Morning, I have implemented your solution but forgive me if I have not done it correctly, as the data object that's being returned by it is identical to what's on the page source.

function GetDigitalData(){
  var page = Sys.Browser().Page("*");
  var dataMapper = 
  page.contentDocument.querySelector('script[class="dataMapper"]').innerHTML
  var x = (dataMapper.substring(23).slice(0, -2))
  var y = JSON.parse(x);
  var digitalData = new Proxy(y,{set:function(target,key,value){target[key]=value;Log.Message({ target });return true;}});
  return digitalData;
}

Comment: I think you will have to reset the global variable `digitalData` to the Proxy so it catches changes. So you will need to remove the `var`. Updated the answer to remove it.

Comment: Still gets the same output as the page source.
However, if I run your digitalData=new Proxy(digitalData,{set:function(target,key,value){target[key]=value;console.log({ target });return true;}}); 
in the browser console I do get the correct updated results, same as when I just enter 'digitalData'.

It must be how I am executing the solution in the testComplete application. As said, I pass it the object from the page source contentDocument. But maybe I shouldn't be.

This leads back to my original question: how does the console actually do it, where does it get that updated object from